# Any suggestion on MySQL services?

Tags: server, mysql

I would like to separate my production server into 2, one for running code, the other one is for DB, which is MySQL.

Is there any suggestion if I would like to subscribe a MySQL service? I have few applications need such standalone database service. So I would like to a service which allow me to create as many database as I want.

Thanks everyone. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this for security reasons? Because if you are, then having your DB on a separate publicly-accessible network sorta defeats the purpose. The idea of keeping web server and DB server on separate servers is so that, while your web server needs to be in a DMZ, your database server should not.

The best thing to do is just find a web host that puts the DB on a separate server, but one that is only accessible from within the network. I don't know of any web hosts like this off hand though.

If you want to separate DB and application for other reasons, then DremaHost offers shared hosting with unlimited MySQL databases, which are hosted on separate servers. Still, even though I like DreamHost and recommend them to everyone, I don't know if this is any reason to switch web hosts.

If you want more scalable database access, then you could try Amazon's SimpleDB or Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS). Both offer cloud data storage; the latter includes a MySQL option, I believe.

Comment: Thanks buddy. The reason i want to separate the DB is.... I am currently using an virtual instance as production server. I want to have a contingency plan if there is any problem with the production server, I can switch to my backup server. If DB is run inside the same production server. I can't access the data if I switch to backup server. Would you please suggest me some way to handle this issue? :)

Comment: Having mysql on a differnt host will slow your site down a bit.  Specially if you query large amounts of data and dont cache results.  I think its bets to find a host that gives you more.  As for a contingency plan, just dump your mysql and have it ftp to a differnt server.  MSSQL has replication which makes this very easy.

Comment: I also think @siulamvictor is looking for replication feature. @Frank, MySQL also has this feature, so I see no point to migrate from MySQL to MSSQL.